# How to drop an a-image such that its rotation is facing user in AR mode?

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, aframe

How to drop an a-image such that its rotation sets it to be facing user in AR mode?

So I have some code along the lines of:

```
    // If the cursor has an intersection, place a marker.
var cursor = sc.querySelector('[ar-raycaster]').components.cursor;

if (cursor.intersection) {
  marker.setAttribute('position', {
    x: cursor.intersection.point.x, 
    y: cursor.intersection.point.y + 0.1, 
    z: cursor.intersection.point.z});

  marker.setAttribute('rotation', {
    x: 0, 
    y: 0, 
    z: 0
  });

}
```

How do I set the x,y,z rotation in such a way it places the image so it is perpendicular to the user (I am using AR View) so the image can be viewed straight on and not from the side?

Answer (score 0):

Ah I just realised I can get the camera rotation and apply that!

```
  var rot = cam.getAttribute('rotation');


  marker.setAttribute('rotation', {
    x: 0,
    y: rot.y, 
    z: 0
  });
```